# Modify master.dbo.syslanguages or insert new language

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, date

In my application we have to call `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` before each and every operation. In the `master.dbo.syslanguages` in entry for my language (polish, lcid=1045) there is `dmy` format.

So is there any way I could change this entry or create a new language that will be like old one, but with changed `DATEFORMAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 removed the option to update system tables that was present in SQL Server 2000 (using `sp_configure 'allow updates', 1`)

Can you not change your client date format so it's recognised correctly regardless of DATEFORMAT settings? eg 4 figure year, ISO formats etc such as (not exhaustive) "21 feb 2008 14:32", "2008-02-21 14:32", "20080221 14:32" etc.